# Add New User, extra fields which are required?

Tags: php, customization, users

I use these two functions to be able to set the first and last name when I go to Add New User:

```
// Add First and Last name to Add New User
function add_new_user_name_fields($user) {
  ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="first_name">First Name</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="last_name">Last Name</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <?php
}
add_action( "user_new_form", "add_new_user_name_fields" );

// Save First and Last name when new user is added
function save_add_new_user_name_fields($user_id) {
    if (!current_user_can('create_users'))
        return false;
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'last_name', $_POST['last_name']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_add_new_user_name_fields');
```

This works very good, but how do I set both these fields to be required? Right now I am able to add a new user without setting anything in these fields.

Lastly, adding these two fields means that they end up on the bottom below `Add the user without sending an email that requires their confirmation.` Is it possible to place these two fields directly below the `Username` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on a multisite? Because otherwise, those two fields are under the "Email" field?

Comment: ... and if you are on a multisite, the central user record should already have first and last names (I think!). To answer the first question anyway, add `class="form-required"` to one of the elements containing your input, e.g. the existing table uses the tr: `<tr class="form-field form-required">`.

Comment: Yes, I am on a multisite, sorry for not clarifying this! `<tr class="form-field form-required">` does solve the issue! However I still cannot figure out how to move the fields to sit below Username.

Comment: @jockebq, there are no hooks - on the "Add New User" page - for adding custom form fields *exactly* before/after the "Username" field. But you can use jQuery/JavaScript to move the fields.